# Java UDP Chat Program: Part of first message gets appended onto second

Tags: java, udp, chat

I'm writing a client-server chat program using UDP. If either the client or the server sends a message, and the next message they send is shorter than the previous one they sent, part of the longer message will be put onto the end of the shorter one. This is my first time using UDP and I've no idea what could be causing this, I made a similiar program using TCP and didn't have this issue.

**What the client sees:**

Client: Hello, how are you?

Server: I'm good thanks, and you?

Client: Great

**What the server sees:**

Client: Hello, how are you?

Server: I'm good thanks, and you?

Client: Great, how are you?

**My server code:**

```
public class ChatServer implements Runnable
{  
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            new Thread(new ChatServer()).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try 
            {
                    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));    

                    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);

                    byte[] receiveData = new byte[65508];
                    byte[] sendData = new byte[65508];

                    System.out.println("Enter a username: ");
                    String serverUsername = inFromUser.readLine();

                    System.out.println("Send message...");

                    while(true)
                    { 
                            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);                   
                            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);       

                            String clientSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                            System.out.println(clientSentence);

                            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();

                            int port = receivePacket.getPort(); 

                            System.out.print("Me: ");
                            String serverSentence = serverUsername + ": " + inFromUser.readLine();

                            sendData = serverSentence.getBytes(); 

                            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);                   
                            serverSocket.send(sendPacket); 
                    }
              } 

              catch (IOException ex) 
              {
                      Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
       }
}
```

**My client code:**

```
public class ChatClient 
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
                BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));       
                try (DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket()) 
                {
                        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");       
                        byte[] sendData = new byte[65508];       
                        byte[] receiveData = new byte[65508];

                        System.out.println("Enter a username: ");
                        String clientUsername = inFromUser.readLine();

                        System.out.println("Send message...");

                        while(true)
                        {      
                                System.out.print("Me: ");
                                String clientSentence = clientUsername + ": " + inFromUser.readLine();
                                sendData = clientSentence.getBytes();
                                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);       
                                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);                                                         

                                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);       
                                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);       
                                String serverSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData()); 
                                System.out.println(serverSentence);
                        }
                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {
                        e.getMessage();
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receive Packet is initially null terminated.
It gets filled in with the network data.
You need to tell the string how many bytes to read or zero out receiveData after each construction of clientSentence.  Using the length of the packet is the correct way to approach this.

Change:

```
   String clientSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
```

To:

```
  String clientSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData() ,0 , receivePacket.getLength());
```